# Replace part of the path in source files listed in dump file when debugging in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We build our releases on a build server that creates a workspace directory for each build. This means that when we try to debug a dump file on a developers machine, Visual Studio asks for the location of every source file. i.e. on build server, source directory may be C:\builds\workspaces\ASDFASDSDFSDF\solution_name\subdir\bob.cpp
but on developers machine it might be:

C:\src\solution_name\XX.YY.ZZ\subdir\bob.cpp

How do you tell Visual Studio to replace
C:\builds\workspaces\ASDFASDSDFSDF\solution_name
with
C:\src\solution_name\XX.YY.ZZ\

in all of the filepaths?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no direct setting option that can meet your needs.

Comment: I worked for a software company of about 100 developers, everybody worked with the same environment as the one of the build servers, hence, as stated by Barnet, I don't think the feature you're asking for does not exist (yet).

Comment: @Dominique - But what if your build server is creating a new temp directory for each build? It's not sustainable. Luckily it appears that VS will deduce the change in the root path once you point it to one of the files its looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after you give Visual Studio the path for one file, it now is able to deduce where the rest of the files are. This is Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.